# Prioritising two absolute elements

Tags: html, css, absolute

I have two absolute elements, which overlap. I would like to have one to show above the other. In the below example, I want the pink figure with text to show above the pseudo-element created with `::before`.
I've tried the `z-index`, but it doesn't seem to help. 
Any ideas?

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
}
.lightbox {
  display: none;
  margin: auto;
}
.links {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.lightbox:target {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
  left: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#close_button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.lightbox #close_button::after {
  content: "x";
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  right: -1rem;
  top: -1rem;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}
figcaption {
  z-index: 1000;
  background: lightpink;
  width: 25rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#close_button::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
  border: solid red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
    <div style="height: 200px; background: lightgreen;">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <a class="links" href="#text1">Open example 1</a>
      <a class="links" href="#text2">Open example 2</a>
    </nav>
    <br><br>
    <div class="lightbox" id="text1">
      <figure>
        <a href="#" id="close_button"></a>
        <figcaption>
          Ipsum lorem ...
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="lightbox" id="text2">
      <figure>
        <a href="#" id="close_button"></a>
        <figcaption>
          Some latin text in textbox2 ...
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `z-index` to work element has to have a position other than `static`. In your case element needs to have `position: relative`

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
}
.lightbox {
  display: none;
  margin: auto;
}
.links {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.lightbox:target {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
  left: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#close_button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.lightbox #close_button::after {
  content: "x";
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  right: -1rem;
  top: -1rem;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}
figcaption {
  z-index: 1000;
  background: lightpink;
  width: 25rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#close_button::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
  border: solid red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
I have following example: https://codepen.io/elenaoat/pen/NzdVda?editors=1100

When you click on the buttons you will see some text popping up. I cannot figure out how to get the text in the figcaption to be "above" the pseudo-element created with before. Right now the pseudo-element covers the whole window, which is fine, but I want the pink div with the text to show above it, so it's not greyed out.

    <div style="height: 200px; background: lightgreen;">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <a class="links" href="#text1">Open example 1</a>
      <a class="links" href="#text2">Open example 2</a>
    </nav>
    <br><br>
    <div class="lightbox" id="text1">
      <figure>
        <a href="#" id="close_button"></a>
        <figcaption>
          Ipsum lorem ...
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="lightbox" id="text2">
      <figure>
        <a href="#" id="close_button"></a>
        <figcaption>
          Some latin text in textbox2 ...
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

Comment: Indeed. But why does it need a position relative? I am trying to understand it logically.

Comment: The top, right, bottom, left, and z-index properties have no effect for position static which is the default value for elements. When position is set to relative it creates a new stacking context when the value of z-index is not auto.

Answer (score 1):

Add position: relative to figcaption and also changed z-index on the after element and the figcaption.

z-index property only works on fixed, absolute or relative divs. So thats why you need the relative position on figcaption and even z-index:2 will work in that case. No need of 1000 value. Similarly, you need just one higher value for the after close icon. So zindex 3 will also work.

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
}
.lightbox {
  display: none;
  margin: auto;
}
.links {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.lightbox:target {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
  left: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#close_button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.lightbox #close_button::after {
  content: "x";
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  right: -1rem;
  top: -1rem;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}
figcaption {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background: lightpink;
  width: 25rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#close_button::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
  border: solid red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
    <div style="height: 200px; background: lightgreen;">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <a class="links" href="#text1">Open example 1</a>
      <a class="links" href="#text2">Open example 2</a>
    </nav>
    <br><br>
    <div class="lightbox" id="text1">
      <figure>
        <a href="#" id="close_button"></a>
        <figcaption>
          Ipsum lorem ...
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="lightbox" id="text2">
      <figure>
        <a href="#" id="close_button"></a>
        <figcaption>
          Some latin text in textbox2 ...
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the figcaption position to relative.